# How to use regex to search all CSS files if any selector does not have a specific property?

Tags: regex

I'm running into an issue on my site where I've found the line-heights are way off on several heading selectors.

I understand how to run a search on only my stylesheets (which there are a lot of them), but I don't understand if there's a way to use regex to search (I use VS Code) for all `h3` selectors that don't have the `line-height` property?

This is where I'm at right now, but this will include `line-height`. I am finding it hard to understand the documentation well enough to disinclude `line-height`.

`(?<=h3 \{)(\n.+)*line-height`

**How do I search all `h3` selectors that don't have a nested `line-height` property?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this :`h3\b.*(?:\r?\n(?!\}|.*\bline-height\b).*)*\r?\n\}\n?` will detect all the h3 that don't contain line-height in your style file

### screenshot inside vscode

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you're looking for is `<h3[^>]*line-height`